# Is there an URL-pattern in LEX similar to /apex/NameOfVisualForcePage?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, url

In Aloha the URL /apex/NameOfVisualForcePage lets Salesforce show the VF-Page named "NameOfVisualForcePage"

Assume LEX = Lightning Experience and SPA = Single Page App

I know LEX is SPA, but that does not mean necessarily to banish URLs in general. All the part after the # could be used, like Salesforce itself does at some places:

- /one/one.app#/setup/ApexClasses/home (e.g. setup-pages)
- /one/one.app#/sObject/Account/home (e.g. record home)
- /one/one.app#/sObject/0010Y00000AaNI4QAN/view (e.g. record view)

**Why I need this?**

I want to talk with team-mates about an particular UI located on one of many VF-tabs without communicating clickpaths.

**What have I tried so far?**

/one/one.app#/apex/NameOfVisualForcePage (does not work)

Is there anything else?

Comment: I assume LEX = Lightning Experience and SPA = Single Page App, but this is the first time I've seen these abbreviated.  Can you expand your abbreviations?

Comment: As an answer to your question, it seems that each of the examples you gave at the top have a "namespace" before the traditional URL.  Perhaps try something like `page/apex/NameOfPage`?

Comment: LEX and SPA are quite typical abbreviations, sorry for that. Your assumption is 100% correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180131/is-it-legal-to-surface-visualforce-in-lex-using-aloharedirect-apex-xxx-url) and [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176033/is-one-one-app-aloharedirect-apex-vfpagename-ideal-solution-to-open-vf-page-in) question ;-)

**TL;DR**: there's a URL hack that seems to allow VF pages to surface in LEX

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that functionality isn't available in LEX. If and when it does become available, you can still write lightning components for your different pages and then nest them inside of visualforce pages which will have it's own URL.