# Is /one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/apex/vfPageName ideal solution to open vf page in lightning experience?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, navigation

We have an issue wherein when a user is redirected to our application from an external point such as an email link and if the user is lightning enabled then the custom VF page does not display the headers and sidebar information properly. In order to resolve this, we have an option.

From the email link we redirect the user to a page which checks if the user is lightning enabled or classic, and if the user is lightning enabled, then we append the URL

```
/one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/apex/vfPageName
```

to our URL and use it to redirect to the required page.

We just want to know if this is the ideal solution or there is some other option to this.

Comment: This seems to work great, but unless SFDC will document this functionality, I'm reluctant to use it in production. I have a need for this as well.

Comment: @sagar-thoriya I am in a similar situation, the only workaround that I think I can come up without using #/alohaRedirect is to detect if header and sidebar are missing in apex page (my pages have them on), when in lighting and show a link to go back to lightning one.app. I am not sure if /one/one.app is also publicly supported. Any Thoughts ?