# Is it "legal" to surface VF Pages in LEX using "#/alohaRedirect/apex/XXX" URL?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, console

I've "discovered" I'm able to surface Visualforce Pages into LEX (console) by using this url format:

https://myorg.lightning.force.com/one/one.app**#/alohaRedirect/apex/My_Visualforce_Page**

I wonder:

- is it a "legal"/documented functionality? I haven't found any indication anywhere
- is it appropriate to use it in a production environment? (maybe this one looks a bit like an opinion based question, but I look for well-founded arguments)

(This question might be a duplicate of [Is /one/one.app#/alohaRedirect/apex/vfPageName ideal solution to open vf page in lightning experience?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176033/is-one-one-app-aloharedirect-apex-vfpagename-ideal-solution-to-open-vf-page-in) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it isn't anything that is *explicitly* documented by Salesforce then unfortunately it would be an unsupported hack or workaround for the time being. If it works, you can continue to use it. However, Salesforce can—at anytime—update or change this behavior which would cause your page to break.